# DepmixS4 fix state order - R

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models

I am using the package depmixS4 to fit a HMM on time-series data. Here is an example with some high vol and low vol data.

In the getpars function we can see the parameter value estimates.

What is happening is that sometimes the first two values in the density are the low vol state and sometimes the second two values are the low vol state. Is there any way to fix (maybe setting initial priors?)

```
set.seed(1)
a <- data.frame(v1 = c(rnorm(n = 100, sd = 10), rnorm(n=100, sd = 1)))
a <- sample(a)
my_model <- depmixS4::depmix(response = v1 ~ 1 ,  nstates = 2 , data = a)
fitted_model <- depmixS4::fit(my_model)
getpars(fitted_model)

for (i in 100:200) {
  my_model2 <- depmixS4::depmix(response = v1 ~ 1 ,  nstates = 2 , data = a[1:i, ,  drop = FALSE])
  fitted_model2 <- depmixS4::fit(my_model2)
  pars <- getpars(fitted_model2)
  if (pars[8] > 8) {
    print(i)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is called **label switching**.

Models in which you swap the label of states (e.g., relabel state 1 as state 2 and state 2 as state 1) have the same likelihood and hence are both valid maximum likelihood solutions.

You can try to "fix" this issue by:

- setting initial values for the parameters (which make it more likely that the EM algorithm will converge to a particular solution, although this is not guaranteed!);
- or by setting order constraints (e.g. forcing the mean for state 1 to be larger than the mean for state 2). Such constraints can be supplied to the fit method in `depmixS4` (see examples in ?fit);
- a final option is to switch the labels of a fitted `depmixS4` object.

Here is a function to relabel a fitted `depmix` object I have used before (not tested well though!):

```
label_switch <- function(mod,labels) {
  # labels is vector, first element is new integer label  for original state integer 1, second is new integer label for original state integer 2, etc.
  if(!is(mod,"depmix") || !is(mod,"depmix.fitted")) stop("this function is for depmix models")
  n_states <- mod@nstates
  if(length(labels) != n_states || length(unique(labels)) != n_states || !(all(labels) %in% 1:n_states)) {
    stop("labels needs to be a vector of unique integers between 1 and", n_states)
  }
  inv_labels <- sapply(1:n_states,function(x) which(labels == x))
  tmp <- mod
  # relabel prior
  ppars <- getpars(mod@prior)
  fpars <- getpars(mod@prior,which="fixed")
  out_pars <- as.numeric(t(matrix(ppars,nrow=length(ppars)/n_states,byrow = TRUE)[,inv_labels]))
  out_fixed <- as.logical(t(matrix(fpars,nrow=length(fpars)/n_states,byrow = TRUE)[,inv_labels]))
  if(!tmp@prior@family$link=="identity") tmp@prior@family$base <- labels[tmp@prior@family$base]
  # relabel transition
  for(i in 1:n_states) {
    ppars <- getpars(mod@transition[[inv_labels[i]]])
    fpars <- getpars(mod@transition[[inv_labels[i]]],which="fixed")
    out_pars <- c(out_pars,as.numeric(t(matrix(ppars,nrow=length(ppars)/n_states,byrow = TRUE)[,inv_labels])))
    out_fixed <- c(out_fixed,as.logical(t(matrix(fpars,nrow=length(fpars)/n_states,byrow = TRUE)[,inv_labels])))
    tmp@transition[[i]] <- mod@transition[[inv_labels[i]]]
    if(!tmp@transition[[i]]@family$link=="identity") tmp@transition[[i]]@family$base <- labels[tmp@transition[[i]]@family$base]
    #out_pars <- c(out_pars,getpars(mod@transition[[inv_labels[i]]]))
  }
  # relabel response
   for(i in 1:n_states) {
    out_pars <- c(out_pars,unlist(lapply(mod@response[[inv_labels[i]]],getpars)))
    out_fixed <- c(out_fixed,unlist(lapply(mod@response[[inv_labels[i]]],getpars,which="fixed")))
   }
  tmp <- setpars(tmp,out_fixed,which="fixed")
  tmp <- setpars(tmp,out_pars)
  if(is(tmp,"depmix.fitted")) tmp@posterior <- viterbi(tmp)
  return(tmp)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the function. Can you share a link or document which shows how I can force the mean for ```state 1``` to be larger than the mean for ```state 2```? Should I do it as - ```depmixS4::fit(my_model2, conrows.upper=1, conrows.lower=0)```? Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Solved the problem by ordering the states by means - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70457818/creating-labels-by-group-mean-in-r/70458465#70458465